# Hibernate CriteriaQuery. Как написать вложенный запрос?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria, criteriabuilder

Есть 2 таблицы - function и tech_expert

function имеет поля id, challenge_id и function_id

tech_expert имеет поля id, function_id, expert_id

Таблица tech_expert хранит в себе ключ function_id из таблицы function

```
    public class FunctionEntity extends BaseEntity<Long> {
    
        @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
        @JoinColumn(name = "FUNCTION_ID")
        private Set<TechExpertEntity> techExperts = new HashSet<>();

        //другие столбцы
    }
```

Написал для них запрос в бд, который получает все challenge_id из таблицы function
для значений function_id из подзапроса и он работает, но пытаюсь его перенести в java в виде CriteriaQuery, но пока не понимаю как переписать полностью этот запрос так, что бы hibbernate в итоге сгенерил запрос аналогичный тому, что написан руками, удалось написать только часть от этого (вложенный запрос)

Гугление на эту тему выдаёт в основном примеры где используется одна Entity

Буду крайне благодарен за любой совет или помощь в этом вопросе

```
SELECT challenge_id FROM function
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT function_id FROM tech_expert where expert_id = '10')));

Subquery subQuery = criteriaQuery.subquery(TechExpertEntity.class);
        Root subRoot = subQuery.from(TechExpertEntity.class);
        Predicate predicate = criteriaBuilder.and(
                criteriaBuilder.equal(subRoot.get("expertId"), "10"));
```

Comment: Не понимаю зачем нужен function_id в function, и почему joincolumn не на owning side

Comment: @Scruffythejanitor - это было сделано до меня, это вводные данные которые нельзя изменить